# Transaction execution and interacting with truffle

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Hotelbooking{

    address receiver;
    function deposit(uint256 _amount) payable public {
        require(msg.value == _amount);
        // nothing else to do!
    }

    function Execution (address _Address, uint _Amount) {
           receiver = _Address;
           receiver.transfer(_Amount);
       }
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

I want to write a block chain application to transfer ether from one account to another

I tried more blogs and stack overflow questions but nothing is helping me.

I deployed using truffle with following commands

> Hotelbooking.deployed().then(function(i){app = i})
>
> app.Execution(web3.eth.accounts[1],10)

I tried every blog and stack overflow q&a. I want to transfer ether from one account to another I am getting following error

> at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd
>   (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
>       at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
>       at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
>       at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
>       at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
>       at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your contract working without modifications. I think it's just how you're interacting with it is causing you problems. Here are the steps I took:

```
$ truffle console --network development
truffle(development)> Hotelbooking.deployed().then(app => app.deposit(10, {value: 10}))
{ tx: '0x54c09f6a4f5eac57ca09bf54c6056e1439bd82c00b06a67680a3b3f490ee8547',
  receipt:
  { transactionHash: '0x54c09f6a4f5eac57ca09bf54c6056e1439bd82c00b06a67680a3b3f490ee8547',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockHash: '0x973414f0c998d8dcd04dca66704b639d93d47a84f1115d110f3d725d2dc83e8b',
    blockNumber: 5,
    gasUsed: 21703,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 21703,
    contractAddress: null,
    logs: [],
    status: '0x01',
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' },
  logs: [] }
truffle(development)> Hotelbooking.deployed().then(app => app.Execution(web3.eth.accounts[1], 10, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}))
{ tx: '0x242bd5f0fc0b7e071e14d85ba269c2b216af67320fc3de2814670772d8269f1b',
  receipt:
  { transactionHash: '0x242bd5f0fc0b7e071e14d85ba269c2b216af67320fc3de2814670772d8269f1b',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockHash: '0xac0fad638722200b102891158d3348493ce3e0bcff63eb54515f845385875756',
    blockNumber: 6,
    gasUsed: 51127,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 51127,
    contractAddress: null,
    logs: [],
    status: '0x01',
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' },
  logs: [] }
```